Complement of all subdiagonals is open in the infinite product topology
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Hausdorff space, and consider the countably infinite product $X^\infty$ with its product topology.
Question.$\quad$ Is the set
$$
X^\infty_\neq := \{ (x_i)_i\in X^\infty : x_i\neq x_j \text{ for all } i \neq j \}
$$
open in $X^\infty$?
If not, can one characterise its interior? (For instance, assume that $X$ is metrisable and let $d$ be a distance metricising its topology. Can one characterise $X^\infty_\neq$ (or its interior) in terms of  $d$?)
Comments.$\quad$ Since $X$ is Hausdorff, the diagonal in $X^2$ is closed. From this one can show that $X^\infty_\neq$ is a $G_\delta$-set since
$$
X^\infty_\neq = \bigcap_{\substack{i,j\\ i\neq j}} \{ (x_k)_k \in X^\infty : x_i \neq x_j\}
$$
and the intersection is countable.

No, it is in fact never open so long as $X$ has infinitely many points (else, $X^\infty_\neq$ is empty so is automatically open).
For let $y$ be any point therein. The claim reduces to the claim that some basic cylinder set $\prod_{j=1}^nU_j\times\prod_{j>n}X$, for open $U_j$ and a finite $n$, contains $y$ and is contained in $X^\infty_\neq$. But this cannot be; this set contains $(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n,y_1,y_1,y_1,y_1,\cdots)$ which is certainly not in $X^\infty_\neq$.

This actually shows that it has empty interior, is it not?

@AlephBeth If a nonempty set has empty interior, that set is not open. $Y\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ iff. $\mathrm{int}_X(Y)=Y$. This cannot both be empty and nonempty!

Apologies: my meaning was "this also shows that the set has empty interior"...

@AlephBeth Oh I see! My bad. Yes, you're right. Equivalently, we say $X^\infty_\neq$ is hollow and we observe that $X^\infty_=:={x\in\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X:x_i=x_j\text{ for at least two distinct $i,j$}}$ is dense. This is maybe easier to realise. This version of the statement is true regardless of any hypothesis on $X$.

However it's still worth noting that the true diagonal $\Delta^\infty=\Delta(X)$, where $\Delta:X\to\prod X$ is the canonical map, is closed (and its complement is open) in the product topology, if $X$ is Hausdorff.
